# Upload documents to SharePoint with Metadata c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, sharepoint-2010, metadata

I am working on a site that makes use of a web service to upload documents to Sharepoint. I have a web service that works and uploads to Sharepoint. However, I need to add metadata to this file being uploaded, such as first name, last name, date of birth etc from a database record, as well as live data from the site. This data is stuff like a 'Workflow number', 'Agreement number', 'Document Type' which gets generated on the site and is associated to that Member and document.

Here is the Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace DCTMAgent
{
    public class SharePoint
    {               
        internal void SPUploader(Stream fs, string fn)
        {
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SharepointSite/Home.aspx");

            System.Net.ICredentials creds = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            context.Credentials = creds;
            context.RequestTimeout = 60000000; // Time in milliseconds

            string url = "/Members/";
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fn);                   

            string fnUrl = url + fn;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fnUrl, fs, true);           
        }       
    }
}
```

How can I change this to upload metadata with the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
    public class SharePoint
        {
            internal void SPUploader(Stream fs, string fn)
             {
                ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://Sharepointsite");///SitePages/Home.aspx");
                System.Net.ICredentials creds = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                context.Credentials = creds;
                context.RequestTimeout = 60000000; // Time in milliseconds

                string url = "/Members/";
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fn);                   

                string fnUrl = url + fn;

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fnUrl, fs, true);

                string uniqueRefNo = GetNextDocRefNo();

                SP.Web web = context.Web;

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fnUrl);
                context.Load(newFile);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                Web site = context.Web;
                List docList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Members");

                context.Load(docList);
                context.ExecuteQuery();


                context.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Workflow Number"));
                context.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Agreement Number"));
                context.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("First Name"));
                context.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Surname"));
                context.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("ID Number"));
                context.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Date of Birth"));
                context.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Country"));
                context.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Document Description"));
                context.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Document Type"));
                context.Load(docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Document Group"));

                context.ExecuteQuery();                                

*********NEED TO GET THE INTERNAL COLUMN NAMES FROM SHAREPOINT************
                var name = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Workflow Number").InternalName;
                var name2 = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Agreement Number").InternalName;
                var name3 = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("First Name").InternalName;
                var name4 = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Surname").InternalName;
                var name5 = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("ID Number").InternalName;
                var name6 = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Date of Birth").InternalName;
                var name7 = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Country").InternalName;
                var name8 = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Document Description").InternalName;
                var name9 = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Document Type").InternalName;
                var name10 = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Document Group").InternalName;
                var name11 = docList.Fields.GetByTitle("Unique Document Ref No").InternalName;     

**********NOW SAVE THE METADATA TO SHAREPOINT**********
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name] = "927015";
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name2] = "1234565";
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name3] = "Joe";
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name4] = "Soap";
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name5] = "7502015147852";
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name6] = "1975-02-01";
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name7] = "ZA";
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name8] = "Test";
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name9] = "Requirements";
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name10] = "Requirements";
                newFile.ListItemAllFields[name11] = uniqueRefNo;

                newFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                context.Load(newFile);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
```